# Symfony2 Entity with criteria and params

Tags: symfony, entity, criteria

I'm trying to create an entity with a oneToMany relation and criteria like this

```
  /**
 * Get translatedData
 *
 * @return translatedData collection
 */
public function getTranslatedData($language) {
    $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("language", $language));
    $result = $this->getAllTranslatedData()->matching($criteria)[0];

    if (count($result) == 0){
        $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("language", 'en'));
        $result = $this->getAllTranslatedData()->matching($criteria)[0];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Basically I want to pass the locale to the entity, so it will return the translatedData in the locale language in the twig template just calling
{{ mainEntity.translatedData.property }} (if there's no translated data in that language, it will fallback to 'en')
but doing a find() on the mainEntity I'm unable to pass any param to this function.

Any idea is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would using a 3rd party library offering such feature be an option? https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable

Comment: Having a look, but I think my problem is easier than this.
Only need to pass the request to the entity or a param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the property `translatedData.property` on your entity you can simply call your method directly in twig:

`{{ mainEntity.getTranslatedData('your_language') }}`

It will allow you to pass a parameter.

Comment: yey! how easy!
Thanks a lot!